# android 3 layout same activity

Tags: java, android, xml, frame

i need help because i want to use 1 activity to rule multi xml files. first time i show 2 layout:

```
LinearLayout layoutMain = new LinearLayout(this);
layoutMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
setContentView(layoutMain);
LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout layoutLeft = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
    R.layout.main2, null);
RelativeLayout layoutRight = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
    R.layout.row, null);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutMain.addView(layoutLeft, relParam);
layoutMain.addView(layoutRight, relParam);
```

then i don't know how to change the bottom layout, when click on button, and change again and again with a lot of other xml part.

```
buttoneva.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

       ///Here the code i need to put
        }
        });
```

The 1 xml file stay this is the second part change few time depend of the action the user do.

(In php is include, in html is frame, but in java android i not sure i do the right way)

I look a lot of tutorial and i have no clue please help me.

the full version of my activity:

```
public class Test extends Activity{


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 ////some useless stuff here
 firstxml();
}

private void firstxml(){
Button buttoneva;
LinearLayout layoutMain = new LinearLayout(this);
layoutMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
setContentView(layoutMain);
LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)       getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout layoutLeft = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
 R.layout.main2, null);
RelativeLayout layoutRight = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
R.layout.row, null);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutMain.addView(layoutLeft, relParam);
layoutMain.addView(layoutRight, relParam);


buttoneva = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1ecrit);



buttoneva.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
  ///here i want to change on click the bottom xml file and keep the first             
  ////one because they have a gif and specific text i dont want to reload 
  secondxml();
 }

 }); 
 }
 private void secondxml(){
 /// ............
 }
```

Comment: What is your minimum supported API level?

Comment: minimum 19 to maximum 21 api

Comment: The **real** question is how you plan to handle the `Back` button (`onBackPressed()` method).

Comment: private void secondxml(){  ///here  } i will do a private void for each xml file i don't want use on back pressed method because that will mess with all my question and answer trick

Comment: No one have a answer?